# Adding numbers and receiving a NaN

Tags: javascript, debugging, math, nan, minecraft

I have this code, its javascript and is using cs.js (Chattriggers for Minecraft 1.8)

```js
register('command', function(...arguments) {
  ChatLib.chat(arguments.length);
  if (arguments.length % 2 != 0) {
    for (argument in arguments) {
      arg = arguments[argument];
      if (isNaN(parseInt(arg))) {
        let num1 = parseFloat(arguments[argument - 1]);
        let num2 = parseFloat(arguments[argument + 1]);
        let equals = 0;
        switch (arg) {
          case "+":
            equals = num1 + num2;
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
            break;
          case "-":
            equals = num1 - num2;
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
            break;
          case "*":
            equals = num1 * num2;
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
            break;
          case "/":
            equals = num1 / num2;
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
            break;
          case "%":
            equals = num1 % num2;
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
            break;
          default:
            ChatLib.chat(`${color.RED}${color.UNDERLINE}WOAH THERE BUCKO! ${color.RESET}${color.GOLD}You're only allowed to do single operations, do /calc help if you need help with the syntax.`);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).setName("calc");
```

Whenever I am running this, with 7 + 3 its returning NaN to me, I have noticed that it is somewhere around the equals areas as when I was doing my debugging that's where it seemed to go wrong. I tried to research as much as I can but I can't find anyone with a similar problem, running through the code I don't see a problem with any of it other than maybe some inefficiency in there. The portion that seems to go wrong is:

```js
equals = num1 + num2;
ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}Success!`);
ChatLib.chat(`${color.GREEN}` + equals.toString());
break;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is becoming very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source of the issue:

```js
for (argument in arguments) {
```

Whilst `arguments` is an array, this is resulting in `argument` being the text property of each element, so you end up iterating over `"0"`, `"1"` and `"2"`.

Where it's being used by itself, eg here:

```js
arg = arguments[argument];
```

It's finding the correct element.  When it gets down to the section where it's attempting to get the previous and next elements, it partly works.  This line is ok:

```js
let num1 = parseFloat(arguments[argument - 1]);
```

This line is not:

```js
let num2 = parseFloat(arguments[argument + 1]);
```

That's because the `-` is casting `argument` to a number before subtracting 1, whereas the `+` operator is doing string concatenation, so you end up looking for:

```js
let num2 = parseFloat(arguments["11"]);
```

Since there's no property 11 on arguments, `num2` ends up being `NaN`.

A simple fix is to update your for loop to explicitly loop over numeric indexes, rather than over the named properties (which in an array happen to be string representation of the numeric indexes):

```js
for (let argument = 0; argument < arguments.length; argument++) {
```

```js
function f(...arguments) {
  console.log(arguments.length);
  if (arguments.length % 2 != 0) {
    for (let argument = 0; argument < arguments.length; argument++) {
      arg = arguments[argument];
      if (isNaN(parseInt(arg))) {
        let num1 = parseFloat(arguments[argument - 1]);
        let num2 = parseFloat(arguments[argument + 1]);
        let equals = 0;
        switch (arg) {
          case "+":
            equals = num1 + num2;
            console.log(`Success!`);
            console.log(equals.toString());
            break;
          case "-":
            equals = num1 - num2;
            console.log(`Success!`);
            console.log(equals.toString());
            break;
          case "*":
            equals = num1 * num2;
            console.log(`Success!`);
            console.log(equals.toString());
            break;
          case "/":
            equals = num1 / num2;
            console.log(`Success!`);
            console.log(equals.toString());
            break;
          case "%":
            equals = num1 % num2;
            console.log(`Success!`);
            console.log(equals.toString());
            break;
          default:
            console.log(`WOAH THERE BUCKO! You're only allowed to do single operations, do /calc help if you need help with the syntax.`);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

f("3", "+", "7")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didnt even think about the fact its a string and not a number